# Java+MySQL - adding "on duplicate key update"

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have the following query I use for a prepared statement:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (`col1_id`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5`, `col6`, `col7`) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" +
            " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `col1`=?, `col2`=?, `col3`=?, `col4=?, `col5`=?, `col6`=?, `col7`=?;
```

**`col1_id`** is a primary key.

Java simplified code (having ommitted try/catch, iterating through my collection to add more statements to the batch etc):

```
  Connection connection = null;
  PreparedStatement statement = null;
  String insertAdwordsQuery = DatabaseStatements.InsertAdwordsData(aProjectID);

  connection = MysqlConnectionPool.GetClientDbConnection(aUserID);
  connection.setAutoCommit(false);      

  statement = connection.prepareStatement(insertAdwordsQuery);

  statement.setInt(1, x);
  statement.setDouble(2, x);
  statement.setLong(3, x);
  statement.setLong(4, x);
  statement.setDouble(5, x);
  statement.setString(6, x);
  statement.setString(7, x);

  statement.addBatch();

  statement.executeUpdate();

  connection.commit();
```

When running this, an exception is generated. Stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 8
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkAllParametersSet(PreparedStatement.java:2603)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.addBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1032)
    ...
```

Why is this occurring and what's the "8 parameter" supposed to be? the code was working fine with a plain **INSERT** statement, but started failing when I added **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**.

Comment: You need to supply arguments for all the `?` (parameter) in your query.

Comment: Off-topic: Why do you quote your column names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what's the "8 parameter"

The very 8th parameter you added to the query:

```
...VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" + " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `col1`=?
          1  2  3  4  5  6  7...                      here it is - 8th!
```

Anyway, you don't actually need parameters tor the duplicated values at all:

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `col1`=values(col1), `col2`=values(col2), 
`col3`=values(col3), `col4`=values(col4), `col5`=values(col5),
`col6`=values(col6), `col7`=values(col7);
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning about redundant binding param (?) for the duplicate values

Answer (score 1):

You have a total of 14 `?` marks i.e. parameters. However while creating the `PreparedStatement` object you are setting only 7.

You need to have the same number of `setter` method as the number of `?` (paramters) in the `PreparedStatement`.

You need to do -

```
statement.setInt(1, x);
statement.setDouble(2, x);
statement.setLong(3, x);
statement.setLong(4, x);
statement.setDouble(5, x);
statement.setString(6, x);
statement.setString(7, x);

// the following should have the values you want to update when there a duplicate key
statement.setInt(8, x);
statement.setDouble(9, x);
statement.setLong(10, x);
statement.setLong(11, x);
statement.setDouble(12, x);
statement.setString(13, x);
statement.setString(14, x);
```

A suggestion - you do not need to quote the column names.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and answer! while it's perfectly functional, the one from "Your Common Sense" looks better, as I don't have to set the same things twice on a statement.